# AFNetworking Operation inside NSOperation

Tags: ios, xml, afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am having some doubts about which is the best way to solve this problem.

In my app I have to parse xml from ~20 different urls. I want to put the logic inside of an NSOperationQueue, so I can split the task of synchronising in smaller tasks that I can add to the queue. Since this task have to connect to an url and I am using AFNetworking, how should I do it?

```
|
|
|------- => Start my OwnXMLOperation
|       |
|       |
|       | -------  => Start the AFNetworking operation inside my OwnXMLOperation
|       |        |
|       x        |
|                | => Download finish, starting the parser inside the success block
|                |
|------- => Anot | her OwnXMLOperation starts without the previous one is finished. 
|       |        |
|       |        |
|       |--------|--------
|       |        |        |
|       x        x => The | parser of the first operation finished.
|                         |
|                         |------- => Start the AFNetworking operation inside my OwnXMLOperation
```

How can I avoid this ugly NSOperation map? I was thinking about overriding an AFNetworking operation, what I don't even know if it is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your goal? Only executing one operation at a time? What would be the purpose of your XML operation?

Comment: I want to add to a queue as many task as xml I have,that will download, parse and save some objects to a core data model.

Comment: Why not just directly add the AFNetworking operations (and set the max concurrent count on the queue)?

Comment: I was thinking in something like this but I don't like to put all the XML parsing code in the success block of the AFNetworking operation. How can I make it with a little code styling? Can you provide me with some code or help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't both with your own XML operation, the AFNetworking operations and queue can provide all of the queue management you require.

To keep things tidy, put your XML parsing into a number of methods (either in the controller class or a/several helper classes if you wish). Then you can call these methods as appropriate from the AFNetworking success blocks.

Be sure to set the maximum concurrent count on the queue if you're going to add 20 operations so you don't flood the network with requests.

Comment: +1 Yep. I know you know this, but for future readers, it's worth noting that there's no point in doing more than a few concurrent network operations because iOS limits how many will actually run concurrently (it was five concurrent network requests, though in iOS 7, I'm only getting four to run concurrently). If you initiate too many concurrent requests, you're unnecessarily using up worker threads and risk having network requests timing out and failing (esp on slow network). A `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of four or five is prudent, while still enjoying concurrency.